# How to call SetState method from within a flutter widget

Tags: flutter, methods, setstate

I need a repeatable method to pass a number of variables (int) and call SetState method on the passed variable.

An example is below where "value" is passed into the testItems Widget and SetState is called on top of "BlueMinusButton".

I have a number of "values" which I need to pass into additional "testItems" methods. However, when I input the variable (as value), SetState is not called and the values do not change.

Any help and / or alternative ways to do this much appreciated.

Thanks

```
int value = 25;

  Widget testItems(int value) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment:
          CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
          textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
          children: [
            Text(value.toString(),
                style: kValues),
            Text("g",
                style: kDarkBlue),
          ],
        ),
        Spacer(),
        BlueMinusButton(
            onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            value = value - 50;
          });      
          if (value < 0) {
            setState(() {
              value = 0;
            });
          }
        }),

      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

first, understand that your code are working. (it's very similar to the main counter example)

[code](https://gist.github.com/thKali/35ea0d03f14e736d7fb9613e08b2052d) i used to test on dartpad.dev

1 value is 25

2 you touch the button

3 the new value is -25

4 value is minus that 0 and sets to 0

5 you re-touch the button

6 value is minus that 0 and sets to 0

7 and here we have an infinity loop...

Is a better practice use Widgets, [don't use FUNCTIONS that return widgets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOyq-eTRhvo&ab_channel=Flutter), especially when working with state

About other method to manage your state, you can try a different approach:

[Value Notifier and Value Notifier](https://medium.com/@JediPixels/flutter-state-management-using-valuenotifier-and-valuelistenablebuilder-a72f4012e710)